# How to get INT variable to QProcess write command?

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, qprocess

Following code works

```
QProcess *p = new QProcess();
p->write("10 cats\n");
```

Now I need to send `int` variable to `write` command.

Something like:

```
QProcess *p = new QProcess();
int i = 10;
p->write(i << " cats\n");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to append variables to then pass them as parameter.

try something like this

```
int i{10};
QString formattedString{QString("%1 cats\n").arg(i)};
QProcess* p = new QProcess();
p->write(formattedString.toStdString().c_str());
```